# ¿Cómo puedo corregir la etiqueta input?

Tags: html, css, input

Quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer para que el texto que quiero ingresar a mi página se ubique automáticamente en el inicio de la primer fila y se ajuste al texto ingresado(ya que al copiar y pegar texto se escribe en una sola fila). Dejo imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el bloque de código html y css que estoy utilizando.

```css
#texto02{font-family: Helvetica,Arial,serif,sans-serif;
    margin: 1px;
    border: solid 1px #80A0FF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    font-size: 25px;
    transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000080;
    background: #80A0FF;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;
}
.texto03{
    width: 600;
    height: 200;
    display: inline-block;  
}
```

```html
   <div id='texto02'>
          <h3>Mensaje Cifrado:</h3>
          <p><input type="text" id='mensaje' class="texto03" contenteditable='true' style="width: 50%; height: 200px;" value="Ingrese su texto" />
          </p>
     </div>
```

Comment: ¿Por que necesitas que sea `contenteditable`? No entiendo por que usas un `input`, se me ocurre que sería mejor un `textarea`

Comment: Por el contenteditable lo leí que era para que el input se ajuste al texto insertable (quizás entendí mal). textarea me lo explicarías por favor, soy nuevo en programación y no vi todavía ese tema.

Comment: en el input utilizo un código js para que cumpla determinados requisitos. Como encriptar y desencriptar texto y el solo uso de minúsculas

Comment: Entonces un `textarea` para este caso es lo más adecuado y no hay necesidad de ponerle `contenteditable`. [Más info acá](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

Comment: Listo ya lo modifiqué, tienes razón el textarea para este caso es mejor. Mi pregunta sería entonces cuando conviene utilizar input? Gracias por la ayuda!.

Comment: Input lo deberías de utilizar cuando quieras crear un formulario, o un sitio donde pongas texto y quieres que el usuario lo modifique, pero en casos como este, donde el texto puede ser muy ámplio, es recomendable utilizar textarea